# Making a grid of spaced items that pieces together clicked ones

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm working on a React project, and can't seem to figure out how to make items come together in a grid. The starting grid looks like this:
[It's spaced out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04rJR.png).

When certain items of the grid are clicked, I want all of the selected items to come together if adjacent. Like this: [Which only works when every button in a row has no margin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1ZSK.png).

I think that using margins is the right approach, but my current attempt at doing so doesn't work considering how every single item has a margin, and so removing the margin of one does nothing.

The grid is a 9x9 square of buttons inside of a div. The css looks like this:

```
/* this is the div the buttons are in */
/* in my original code, the size of the grid is customizable. If you make a code example with manually typed divs, just replace the var(--grid-size)*/
.keenboard {
  display: grid;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--grid-size), 1fr);
}

/* these are the buttons */
.keensquare {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(153, 153, 153);
  background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
  margin: 0px;
  transition: background-color 0.15s;
}
```

and currently all the code does is toggle the margin of any square from 0 to 3 when it's clicked.

Thanks in advance to anyone willing to help!

Comment: Your CSS and HTML do not work: https://jsfiddle.net/tu14vhbk/. It also looks like you have not included any code for the clicked behavior.

Comment: @Leland The grid size is supposed to be customizable, so I had to make the repeat() with a variable. If you replace ```var(--grid-size)``` with 9, it works. My bad for not clarifying.

Comment: What does "come together" actually mean in this context? Which one should move? This will vary depending on the number of adjacent squares too. You will need to define that logic first before attempting to go further. For example, when you have one above the other, should the bottom one move up? If you have one with others either side, should only the side ones move? Without changing size, this will result in them no longer lining up exactly with the grid.